# Get native REST service error in Unirest

Tags: java, json, unirest, mashape

We are using Unirest as REST client. Below is the sample code using which we are invoking REST service

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest
  .post(url)
  .header(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HEADER_VALUE_APPLICATON_JSON)
  .body(payload)
  .asJson();
```

This is absolutely when REST service returns json. In case of error, REST service that I am using is not returning json response. Instead it returns html error page.

Since Unirest is trying to convert the html into json, getting the following issue

```
Caused by: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
```

In this case we are just getting this InvalidJsonException and the actual html error page is lost. We need to display the html error page in our application in case of error.

How can we get the original REST service error, in situation like this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the service or the client you're using but should you even be trying to parse the response in case of an error? Maybe you should check the status code before trying to interpret the response body as JSON?

Comment: @toniedzwiedz - Unfortunately Getting the status before parsing the response is not available in Unirest :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you cannot rely on the returned content type, the **workaround** is to treat the response as String:

```
  HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest
      .post(url)
      .header(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, HEADER_VALUE_APPLICATON_JSON)
      .body(payload)
      .asString();
```

This way you will have access to the return status code. Unirest will not try to parse the result to JSON, so you need to do it yourself (if the status code indicates success).